# SDL-2: Trouble running native cocoa application in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, sdl, sdl-2

I'm curious if anybody could help with a problem I'm having. I just downloaded and installed the SDL 2 framework, along with the example programs that come with it, from Mercurial (http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php) onto OSX Mavericks (10.9).

I am attempting to run the example native cocoa code in Xcode 5.1.1, which includes the files `testnative.h`, `testnative.c`, and `testnativecocoa.m` that come from the tests folder in the Mercurial download.

I am successfully able to build the program, but as soon as it hits the function `SDL_CreateWindowFrom(native_window)`, the program crashes and highlights the following line of a file called `SDL_cocoakeyboard.m`:

```
 nswindow = ((SDL_WindowData*)window->driverdata)->nswindow;  Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
```

The only thing I did with the original files was change the include headers from `SDL.h` and `SDL_syswm.h` to `SDL2/SDL.h` and `SDL2/SDL_syswm.h` in `testnative.h`. I've included both the cocoa and SDL2 frameworks in the program, and I turned off automatic reference counting, which was necessary to get the example code running.

I have no idea where else I could be going wrong, since the code before the aforementioned line looks and runs fine (it's able to create the cocoa window before it crashes).

Any insight on this issue would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, still looking into but I think for some reason `window` or `driverdata` is wrongly set to 0x8

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in the comment, `driverdata` is `null` (never initialized), some code like `SDL_cocoawindow.m:SetupWindowData` would be required, but `SetupWindowData` is `static` (not global) and adding a minimal initialization would require `SDL_cocoawindow.h`(but isn't public).

So, my guess (maybe I'm wrong) this *testnative* isn't working, at least not with current SDL2 (the wrong `#include` should have been a sign) but a fast look into SDL2 shown there's enough cocoa code to hope there are other ways to get a native window working.

A good start [How to set up a SDL 2 project for OS X in Xcode 4](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2013/08/22/how-to-set-up-a-sdl-2-project-for-os-x-in-xcode-4/)